# C# event in unity is always null despite assignment, why?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

The past two days I've been struggeling with a basic event system in my unity game. For some context, the game has an exercise system in which interactive objects trigger an event to trigger the exercise validators, which determine if the exercise has been completed.

I have an abstract class `Interactive`, which holds the basic event and it's trigger:

```cs
public abstract class Interactive : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event EventHandler Interacted;

    protected virtual void OnInteraction()
    {
        Interacted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The abstract class is implemented in an interactive object, for now the ShootingTarget:

```cs
public class ShootingTarget : Interactive, IHitable
{
    public HitType OnHit(Gun gun, RaycastHit raycastHit)
    {
        var partHit = GetHitboxTypeFromHit(raycastHit);
        var hitType = HitType.Miss;

        if (Goals.Contains(partHit))
        {
            hitType = HitType.Right;
        }

        else if (Unwanted.Contains(partHit))
        {
            hitType = HitType.Unwanted;
        }

        OnInteraction();
        return hitType;
    }
}
```

The exercise script is bound to an empty object in unity. It has a property `public Interactive[] Interactives;` in which the interactive object for this exercise are set to through the unity inspector. On `Start()` the exercise class loops through the provided interactive objects and sets the event handler for each `.Interacted` event:

```cs
public class Exercise : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Interactive[] Interactives;

    public ExerciseValidator[] ExerciseValidators;

    public void Start()
    {
        foreach (var interactive in Interactives)
        {
            interactive.Interacted += OnInteractionHandler;
        }
    }

    public void OnInteractionHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var exerciseValidator in ExerciseValidators)
        {
            exerciseValidator.Validate();
        }
    }
}
```

The goal is that when `ShootingTarget.OnHit()` is called, `ShootingTarget.OnInteraction()` will be triggered, which should through the `ShootingTarget.Interacted` event trigger `Exercise.OnInteractionHandler()`.

However, during debugging, `ShootingTarget.Interacted` [will always be null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKNhZ.png). Despite having `Exercise.OnInteractionHandler()` [bound to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5JeV.png). I've tried assigning a unique Id to the object to make sure it's the same one during runtime, which it was. Does anyone have a clue why this doesn't work? A helping hand would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure both are the same component or is it possible that it is called for another object which you didn't add to the `Interactives` array?

Comment: @derHugo I've tested with a clean scene that contains only one object which implements the `Interactive` abstraction. I've also tried assigning a unique Id in `Exercise.Start()` to that object to verify that it is the same object when the null reference problem occurs in `ShootingTarget.OnInteraction()`, so my assumption is that it is indeed the same object.